# Equivalent definition of continuous at a point in a topology space

Tags: general-topology

When we want to discuss if a function $f : X \to Y$ is continuous at a point $x \in X$, can we build a new topology on set $X$ and $Y$ (depending on the previous topology and $x$), such that the concept of continuous at point $x$ is equivalent to $f$ being a continuous function up to the new topology?

Comment: If I were to guess I would try $\{U\subset X~:~U\text{ is open, and }x\in U\}$ and keep the topology on $Y$.

Comment: Do you mean something like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_topology or like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Definition_in_terms_of_neighborhoods

Answer (score 0):

Let $(X, \tau_1)$ and $(Y, \tau_2)$ be our topological spaces, and fix $x_0 \in X$. Define a new topology
$$\tau'_1 = \{\mathcal{U}' \subseteq X : x_0 \in \mathcal{U}' \implies \left(\exists \, \mathcal{U} \in \tau_1 : x_0 \in \mathcal{U} \subseteq \mathcal{U}'\right)\}.$$
Essentially, $\tau_1'$ makes every point except $x_0$ discrete, but preserves the neighbourhoods of $x_0$ to an extent.

I claim that $f : (X, \tau'_1) \to (Y, \tau_2)$ is a continuous map if and only if $f : (X, \tau_1) \to (Y, \tau_2)$ is continuous at $x_0$.

Suppose $f$ is continuous with $\tau_1'$ equipped. Given any open neighbourhood $f(x_0) \in \mathcal{V} \in \tau_2$, we can therefore find some $\mathcal{U}' \in \tau_1'$ such that $x_0 \in \mathcal{U}$ and $f(\mathcal{U}') \subseteq \mathcal{V}$. Since $x_0 \in \mathcal{U}'$, this means that there is some $\mathcal{U} \in \tau_1$ such that $x_0 \in \mathcal{U} \subseteq \mathcal{U}'$. Thus, $f(\mathcal{U}) \subseteq f(\mathcal{U}') \subseteq f(\mathcal{V})$, proving continuity of $f$ at the point $x_0$ under $\tau_1$.

Suppose $f$ is continuous at the point $x_0$ with $\tau_1$ equipped. Fix $\mathcal{V} \in \tau_2$. If $f(x_0) \notin \mathcal{V}$, then $x_0 \notin f^{-1}(\mathcal{V})$. Note that this implies vacuously that $f^{-1}(\mathcal{V}) \in \tau'_1$.

Otherwise, $f(x_0) \in \mathcal{V}$, i.e. $x_0 \in f^{-1}(\mathcal{V})$. By continuity at the point $x_0$, there exists some $\mathcal{U} \in \tau_1$ such that $x_0 \in \mathcal{U} \subseteq f^{-1}(\mathcal{V})$. This implies $f^{-1}(\mathcal{V}) \in \tau'_1$, as required, completing the proof.

Answer (score 0):

If $\tau$ is the topology on $X,$ you can define a new topology $\tau_x$ as the set of all subsets $U\subseteq X$ such that, if $x\in U$ then there is some $V\in\tau$ such that $x\in V$ and $V\subseteq U.$

Then a function $f:X\to Y$ is continuous at $x$ if it is continuous from $(X,\tau_x)$ to $Y.$

You can show that a function which is continuous at every point $x\in X$ is continuous as $(X,\tau)\to Y.$